# Pyspark execution issue

Tags: java, python, apache-spark

when I am trying to run pyspark script it gives me following error

```
(base)  spark-submit SparkLinearRegression.py 
20/05/05 06:52:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/koke/anaconda3/bin/jupyter", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/koke/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 230, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "/Users/koke/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 133, in _jupyter_abspath
    'Jupyter command `{}` not found.'.format(jupyter_subcommand)
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-/Users/koke/Data/MLCourse/SparkLinearRegression.py` not found.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I have changed to java8 instead of java10 as default jdk in bash_profile, didn't work.
Please help..

Comment: What are the values of `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` environment variables? For some reason, Jupyter got involved in all of it.

Comment: # export JAVA_HOME=/$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/koke/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/Users/koke/anaconda3/bin/python3
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"

Comment: You should update your question and make it explicit that you are trying to run PySpark script through Jupyter.

Comment: It worked when I commented them out

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: for example I am running spark-submit script.py

Comment: Use the edit link. You’ve already edited once.